# network etiquette, pinging, network connectivity and DDOS

Tags: debian, networking, monitoring, ping

I have a somewhat painful net service provider. In order to mitigate the issue, I usually use something like

```
$ ping debian.org
```

which basically goes ad infinitium unless I break it via `CTRL+C`

I find pinging outside the host country is much more effective than pinging a domestic/same country server as at times international connections die down but the state internet services are still good.

I have two queries -

a. Is there some sort of net etiquette I should follow when pinging or is the above fine or should I use some other technique ?

This is the kind of output I get when it's functionally normally -

```
64 bytes from mirror-isc3.debian.org (149.20.4.15): icmp_seq=38700 ttl=51 time=274 ms
64 bytes from mirror-isc3.debian.org (149.20.4.15): icmp_seq=38701 ttl=51 time=275 ms
64 bytes from mirror-isc3.debian.org (149.20.4.15): icmp_seq=38702 ttl=51 time=273 ms
64 bytes from mirror-isc3.debian.org (149.20.4.15): icmp_seq=38703 ttl=51 time=274 ms
```

when it doesn't work it spews errors like these -

```
From _gateway (192.168.1.1) icmp_seq=38683 Destination Net Unreachable
From _gateway (192.168.1.1) icmp_seq=38684 Destination Net Unreachable
From _gateway (192.168.1.1) icmp_seq=38686 Destination Net Unreachable
From _gateway (192.168.1.1) icmp_seq=38687 Destination Net Unreachable
From _gateway (192.168.1.1) icmp_seq=38689 Destination Net Unreachable
```

b. I do know that there is in existence [ping flood of death](https://www.incapsula.com/ddos/attack-glossary/ping-of-death.html)

Could the simple ping be misused in sending ping of death via various computers and my ping/computer would be an accomplice without meaning to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could the simple ping be misused in sending ping of death via various computers and my ping/computer would be an accomplice without meaning to?

No.

- The Ping of Death is a kind of attack carried out by sending a specially crafted ICMP packet to a (unpatched) machine in order to crash it.
- A ping flood is a DoS attack where one sends a overwhelming amount of ICMP packets. On many UNIX systems only the root user can send a ping flood with zero interval.

None of these apply to you. A normal ping barely takes any resource. You can increase the ping interval or change periodically the target host if it makes you feel better, but pinging remote machines is a reasonable network activity.